# How can I align a multiple-line footnote text right to the footnote mark?

Tags: indentation, footnotes

How can I have the following "footnote layout"?

```
Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text² Some Text 

2 FOOTNOTETEXT FOOTNOTETEXT FOOTNOTETEXT FOOTNOTETEXT FOOTNOTETEXT
  FOOTNOTETEXT FOOTNOTETEXT FOOTNOTETEXT FOOTNOTETEXT FOOTNOTETEXT
```

My problem is that the footnote text starting with the second line is too far left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}    
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way is using the `hang` option of the `footmisc` package; control the separation between margin and text using `\footnotemargin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}

\begin{document} 
\null\vfill   % just for the example
\lipsum*[4]Test\footnote{\lipsum[4]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another option using `scrextend` (notice that, in this case, the marker is not set as superscript before the footnote text):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\deffootnote[10pt]{10pt}{10pt}{\makebox[10pt][l]{\thefootnotemark\hspace{10pt}}}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill
\lipsum*[3]Test\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second mandatory argument to `\deffootnote` is the paragraph indent for the footnote text. Did you choose `10pt` for this on purpose? The default in the `article` class seems to be `8.5pt`

Comment: I have used both answers you provided but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, that's a really useful package. Killed three birds with that stone.

Comment: In my document, `\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}` did not work, but I found out that there is an incompatibility with Babel-french (`\usepackage[french]{babel}`), because it redefines the footnote number mark. I had to add `\frenchsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}`.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment to Gonzalo's answer, using `\deffootnote` of package `scrextend`, it is possible to make the marker as superscript. Just add \textsuperscript into \deffootnote. Include the following code in the preamble of the document.

```
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[10em]{10em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\,}
```