# How to align footnotes

Tags: xetex, footnotes

I'm using XeLaTeX with the `dblfnote` package for two columns of footnotes and a modified footnote command to use letters instead of numbers. Currently my footnotes seem to be in a paragraph format, but I want them all aligned where the first line of text starts (aligned with text, not with the footnote marker). This is what it does currently:

[image: Current footnote alignment]

I'd like it to behave like this, with the same indent it currently has inititally:

```
a Sed at urna vitae libero pulvinar aliquam. In hac 
  habitasse platea dictumst.
b Curabitur luctus leo in nunc tempus, eu fringilla quam 
  porttitor.
c Vivamus semper rhoncus nisl, vitae tempus tellus tris-
  tique vel.
```

Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{dblfnote}

\newcommand{\cv}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1:#2}}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\itshape\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\huge Title}
\end{center}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footnote{Sed at urna vitae libero pulvinar aliquam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.} Integer a eros quis nibh pharetra pellentesque. Mauris molestie purus ut arcu ullamcorper, ut mollis ligula molestie. Ut auctor et augue ac ultrices.\footnote{Curabitur luctus leo in nunc tempus, eu fringilla quam porttitor.} Nulla aliquam quis nunc et aliquet. Nullam eu ligula at leo scelerisque euismod.\footnote{Vivamus semper rhoncus nisl, vitae tempus tellus tristique vel.} Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin at eros at leo sagittis viverra.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}` should help, see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126877/5049

Comment: @cgnieder thanks but that gives an error with this MWE: `! Undefined control sequence.
\@makecol ...\@elt \dfn@elt@getht \dfn@list \@nil 
                                                  \ifdim \@tempdima =\z@ \el...`

Comment: @Dan Put it before `\usepackage{dblfnote}` for compatibility issues.

Comment: I flagged the question as a duplicate (no VTC rep)