# How to justify footnotes, with each row right of the number

Tags: footnotes, indentation

LaTeX newcomer here. Working on a paper, and I'm trying to make my footnotes look more or less like this:

[image]

I got rid of the divider and increased the space between main text and footnote, but I have not been able to format the indentation and alignment properly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: Try: `\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}`. (But it is always better to provide a MWE: it helps you get the help you want/need more quickly becuase it helps people who want to help you see where the roots of the problem lie.)

Comment: Thanks all, for the tips. Clearly still learning the ropes! Found an answer that worked here:

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126877/how-can-i-align-a-multiple-line-footnote-text-right-to-the-footnote-mark?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

Load the package `footmisc` (as suggested by jon) with the option `norule` to suppress the rule and `hang` to have the indentation on every line.

Then adjust the values of the lengths `\footnotemargin` (for the indentation) and `\skip\footins` (for the spacing between footnotes and text).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage[norule,hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{1em}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{3em}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want your footnotes to be bottom-aligned with the page, add the option `bottom` when loading `footmisc`:

```
\usepackage[bottom,norule,hang]{footmisc}
```

Comment: Add the option `bottom` to `footmisc` to move the footnotes to the bottom of the page, or use `scrartcl`from KOMAscript.

Answer (score 1):

An example using [KOMAscript](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % just for the example

\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{%
\makebox[1em][l]{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}}
% Documented at page 83 in the manual
\setfootnoterule{0pt} %% no rule

% Distance text -- footnote
\setlength{\skip\footins}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\par
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

If you have lot of footnotes, you may change the first and third `em` to add more space for the footnote numbers. If you do not want the footnotemark in superscript, just remove the `\textsuperscript{}`, i.e.:

```
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{%
\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thefootnotemark}}
```

And the footnotes in KOMAscript are flushed to the bottom of the pages, looking much nicer when you have a page running short of text.